# Latex3 replacement for \afterassigment in parsing code to grab integer

Tags: latex3, parsing

When parsing expressions, one way that I like to grab an integer delimited on the end by any nonexpandable token that is not a digit is using a count register and `\afterassignment`. So the code looks like:

```
\newcount\mycount
\def\mycommand#1{\mycommand@#1\nil}
\def\mycommand@{\afterassignment\mycommand@@\mycount=}
\def\mycommand@@#1\nil{integer: "\the\mycount", rest: "#1"}
```

so then `\mycommand{12 and text}` produces `integer: "12", rest: "and text"`. For an example of why I would want to do this, see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470171/23866. The asker wanted a command that takes as argument a specification like

```
column 10 to 12 row 3 to 5
column 10 row 7
row 3 to 5
```

Is there a sanctioned latex3 approach to this?

Comment: Why not just use delimited arguments?  `\def\grab column#1to#2row#3to#4\endgrab{...}`

Comment: I edited it to include some cases where it the format isn't exactly the same, so that I don't know exactly what token follows the number.

Comment: The answer is going to be 'no' or at least 'not at the moment': we've not come across a place where such an interface is required.